# Error at ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-studio-2015

I'm not a very good programmer, but I think the codes are correct. Can anyone check if there are errors in it, because I always get an error at the executenonquery line.

The error is:

> {"Incorrect syntax near '9'." & vbCrLf & "Unclosed quotation mark
>   after the character string ',@memberpic)'."}
>
> and/or
>
> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '9'.

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    cn.Open()
    Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblMembers(name, contactno, address, birthday, baptism, ministry, memberpic)VALUES('" & txtName.Text & "','" & txtContactNo.Text & "','" & txtAddress.Text & "',''" & dtpBirthday.Text & "','" & dtpBaptism.Text & "','" & txtMinistry.Text & "',@memberpic)", cn)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@memberpic", SqlDbType.Image)).Value = IO.File.ReadAllBytes(a.FileName)
        i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
    End Using
    If (i > 0) Then
        MsgBox("Save " & i & " record successfully")
        Clear()
    End If
    cn.Close()
    ShowRecord()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the strings in one of the `TextBox` elements probably contains a single quote `'`.

My advice, save yourself some pain and parameterize all of the values in your SQL statement. This is good programming practice for a myriad of reasons, but it will also solve your immediate need of escaping strings that may come from a `TextBox`.

First you tokenize your SQL statement.

```
...
VALUES(@name,@contactno,@address,@birthday,@baptism,@ministry,@memberpic)
```

Then, you set your parameters

```
... 
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlClient.SqlParameter("@name", SqlDbType.Varchar)).Value = txtName.Text
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error says you need to close the single quotes for the string

```
& "',@memberpic)"
```

should be

```
& "',@memberpic) '"
                ^^^^
```